# React: Error referencing a function within state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

the problem seems simple, but I can't figure out how to solve it:

- Add-Button declared within the `render`-Function works just fine
- Add-Button declared within the `state` itself doesn't work. As the code already mentions, it will throw the `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"`-Error

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      someArrayOfObjects: [{
          attr: 
             // SNIP ...
                // Doesn't work!
                // When clicked leads to this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
                <button onClick={this.doAction}>Add</button>
             // SNIP ...
        }]
    };

    this.doAction = this.doAction.bind(this);
  }

  // SNIP ...
  doAction() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
      return(
          // SNIP...
          // Works just fine
          <button onClick={this.doAction}>Add</button>
      )
  }
}
```

What am I missing out?

Comment: Try using an arrow function `<button onClick={() => this.doAction}>Add</button>`

Comment: If you are going to bind doAction, do it before passing it to the component in the state declaration. Otherwise, this will be undefined when that function is called.

Comment: @Sam thanks but the arrow-function didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the function `doAction` before the `state`

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.doAction = this.doAction.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      someArrayOfObjects: [{
          attr: 
             // SNIP ...
                // Doesn't work!
                // When clicked leads to this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
                <button onClick={this.doAction}>Add</button>
             // SNIP ...
        }]
    };

  }
```

**Edit**:
You need to bind the function before the state creation. At the point at which you are creating the button in the state, `this.doAction` refers to the prototype method of the component class. But you [can't pass a method as a callback directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback), so you need to bind it. `Function.prototype.bind` [creates a *new* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which you then assign to the instance being created in the constructor:

```
this.doAction = this.doAction.bind(this);
```

So, perhaps confusingly, `this.doAction` refers to two *different* functions at different points in the code. You want to pass the bound version to the handler (see link above for why), so you need to bind it before creating that button.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it could be improved by explaining *why*.

Comment: @JaredSmith added some explanation, I think it's not the best :/ I could not write it better

Comment: That was a pretty good first pass at it. I touched it up for you, let me know if you have any questions or feel free to edit it further yourself if you think something could be clearer. Nice answer.

Comment: @rMonteiro thanks that works like a charm. Wonder why I didn't try moving the line to the top on my own. However: Should I always put them to the top? Or are there any drawbacks?

Comment: @trynalearn I think there's none drawback by putting the binds in the top, but you only need to do that in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/young-architecture-0r1tk

Here you can see that we need to define the method before adding that into state.
As first we need to define `doAction` method then state,as it is used inside state.

Comment: This should be an edit to rmontiero's answer, as it does not stand on its own as an answer.